# WPF multiple DataGrids in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

Is it possible to put multiple DataGrids inside a ListView?  Something like

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Schools.Teachers}" />
</ListView>
```

Where the classes are:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<School> Schools { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public ObservableCollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Ranking { get; set; }
}
```

And the output would be basically a list of `DataGrid`s, one `DataGrid` for each `School`.

```
School1
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Name            | ID            | Address       | Ranking       |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Teacher1 Name   | Teacher1 ID   | Teacher1 Addr | Teacher1 Rank |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Teacher2 Name   | Teacher2 ID   | Teacher2 Addr | Teacher2 Rank |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+

School2
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Name            | ID            | Address       | Ranking       |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Teacher1 Name   | Teacher1 ID   | Teacher1 Addr | Teacher1 Rank |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Teacher2 Name   | Teacher2 ID   | Teacher2 Addr | Teacher2 Rank |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

How would I structure the xaml for this kind of display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid would be declared in a DataTemplate that is assigned to the ItemTemplate property of the ListBox (unless you set the View property of a ListView, use the simpler base class ListBox).

Inside the DataTemplate the Binding would be `ItemsSource="{Binding Teachers}"`.

For details, see [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Teachers}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```